# TextBox Changed event

Tags: c#

Instead of immediately calling function when text box is changed. I want to wait until a certain word is  entered from a string. However the code I have written does not seem to work. Can anyone inform me f the correct approach to this.

```
private void txtConsole_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FastModeTest = "";
        if (FastModeTest.IndexOf("ADR=") > -1)
        {
            TestRoutine2();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? What `TestRoutine2()` method do? And since you assign your `FastModeTest` to empty string, your `FastModeTest.IndexOf("ADR=") > -1` always returns `false`. Because it's always equal to `"".IndexOf("ADR=") > -1` which is equal `-1 > -1` which is `false`.

Comment: It calls a function. However the function is not being called

Comment: Thank you CKocer works a charm

Comment: which UI-framework? asp.net, winforms, wpf?? please adapt your tags accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void txtConsole_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (txtConsole.Text != "SOMEWORD")
        return;

    // rest
}
```

this code will cancel this function if certain key is not entered.